# How do I fix this error: "Your bundle only supports platforms [] but your local platforms are ["ruby", "x86_64-darwin-19"], and there's no compati..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I run `bundle install` this is the response I get

**"Your bundle only supports platforms [] but your local platforms are ["ruby",
"x86_64-darwin-19"], and there's no compatible match between those two lists."**

I have googled the error but can't find an answer that works for me, the error itself seems to be uncommon.

I ran `bundle env`, and this is what I get.

### Environment

```
Bundler       2.1.4
  Platforms   ruby, x86_64-darwin-19
Ruby          2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091eafcce70ffb75ddf7e121e192ab217) [x86_64-darwin19]
  Full Path   /Users/cykalu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/bin/ruby
  Config Dir  /Users/cykalu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/etc
RubyGems      3.1.4
  Gem Home    /Users/cykalu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  Gem Path    /Users/cykalu/.gem/ruby/2.7.0:/Users/cykalu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  User Home   /Users/cykalu
  User Path   /Users/cykalu/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  Bin Dir     /Users/cykalu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/bin
Tools         
  Git         2.23.0
  RVM         not installed
  rbenv       rbenv 1.1.2
  chruby      not installed
```

### Bundler Build Metadata

```
Built At          2020-01-05
Git SHA           32a4159325
Released Version  true
```

### Bundler settings

```
deployment
  Set for the current user (/Users/cykalu/.bundle/config): true
path
  Set for your local app (/Users/cykalu/Documents/GitHub/rails_app/.bundle/config): "vendor/bundle"
```

### Gemfile

#### Gemfile

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

#### Gemfile.lock

Comment: can you post the whole trace? I know it's probably a lot but I think it will help.

Comment: That is all it says `Your bundle only supports platforms [] but your local platforms are ["ruby", "x86_64-darwin-19"], and there's no compatible match between those two lists.`

You can check the updated question.

Comment: Is the ‘Gemfile.lock’ really empty?

Comment: Are you able to run `gem install bundler` and `bundler -v` ?

Comment: The Gemfile.lock file doesn't get generated at all. I can run `gem install bundler` and `bundler -v`

Answer (score 12):

try: `bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux`

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
$ bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux --add-platform ruby
$ bundle install
$ git add . ; git commit -m "Fix bundler issue"
```

For more details please [see the "Remediation" section under this heroku-buildpack-ruby issue](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/issues/1106).

Answer (score 5):

You are getting this error because of the `deployment` setting in your `~/.bundle/config` being set to `true`. Do you recall adding this to your computer? If this is your development machine, you shouldn't use that Bundler setting. What's happening is that when `deployment` is `true`, Bundler expects a `Gemfile.lock` to already be checked into version control, and because yours is blank, it can't find any platforms listed, and you get that error about the bundle only supporting platforms [] because there are none.

So, to be able to generate the `Gemfile.lock` with `bundle install`, you need to open up your `~/.bundle/config` and remove this line:

```
BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT: "true"
```